# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#create when I use sorcery gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I followed everything about sorcery in railscasts but when I tried to create a user, it gives me this error

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: users.username may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "crypted_password", "email", "salt", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

please help me to fix this problem, please go have a look my github:https://github.com/simpsonness/test_app

Thanks~~~

Comment: post the relevant code of your application

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To get the best answer to your problem, you need to post a "good question".  Please check the guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.   Your question will be improved by posting the code around the code the generates this SQL.  You also might want to check: why is it that you are inserting values for a user into your Users table without including a username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `username` column, create a migration that would delete it:

```
bundle exec rails g migration remove_username_from_users username:string
```

and run it. Otherwise, add `:username` to permitted params in your `UsersController#user_params` private method and add appropriate field to your view.

Answer (score 1):

Message means that you haven't set `username` field for your new User record. There's a way to fix it. In your `app/views/users/new.html.erb` file, you need to add a `username` field. So, it will look like the following:

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

Also, you need to fix parameter filtering in your `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`. Update your `user_params` method with this:

```
def user_params  
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)
end
```

That's it! It should work by now.